rotate axis of tikzpicture to show bars in horizontal direction
Example:
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
    %

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=3.208in,
    height=2.406in,
    at={(2.042in,1.531in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={x},
    ymin=-0.0732000000000001,
    ymax=1.2732,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={y},
    axis background/.style={fill=white}
    ]
    \addplot [color=mycolor1, only marks, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0.767861601282467   0.3458589136031\\
    0.756680548341953   0.95864147735458\\
    0.787814379362316   0.615634775664367\\
    0.482346943930302   0.140139439118997\\
    0.788420766278634   0.252324016431217\\
    0.609541593446003   0.833025781488994\\
    0.598497835040654   0.447882785562502\\
    0.962167060742761   0.297077799336121\\
    0.0672914051246174  0.829030827812664\\
    0.0685031200093895  0.257294078290989\\
    0.979842293331438   0.250600951574307\\
    0.679902746964661   0.934100057924172\\
    0.510673213422503   0.650716813847921\\
    0.650982431174077   0.324690703869729\\
    0.587879973826315   0.167319776765514\\
    0.25698833084105    0.271900912155622\\
    0.986921712124531   0.323353384105197\\
    0.624261860962849   0.330737351577275\\
    0.871562473469132   0.701588447496151\\
    0.148334408564265   0.503016243850673\\
    0.267655595945384   0.838096145967706\\
    0.43063392865761    0.877759753558797\\
    0.220588538068738   0.897891019472078\\
    0.729660418601116   0.899526138648854\\
    0.708895728868174   0.291546924111268\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=1.266in,
    height=2.406in,
    at={(0.19in,1.531in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    ymin=-0.012,
    ymax=1.212,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none
    ]
    \addplot[ybar interval, fill=mycolor1, fill opacity=0.6, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
    x   y\\
    0   1.06666666666667\\
    0.3 0.8\\
    0.6 1.2\\
    0.9 0.266666666666667\\
    1.2 0.266666666666667\\
    };
    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    -0.0600000000000001 0\\
    1.26    0\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=3.208in,
    height=0.827in,
    at={(2.042in,0.216in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    ymin=-0.0146666666666667,
    ymax=1.48133333333333,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none
    ]
    \addplot[ybar interval, fill=mycolor1, fill opacity=0.6, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
    x   y\\
    0   0.8\\
    0.3 0.666666666666667\\
    0.6 1.46666666666667\\
    0.9 0.4\\
    1.2 0.4\\
    };
    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    -0.0600000000000001 0\\
    1.26    0\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=5.833in,
    height=4.375in,
    at={(0in,0in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
    ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}

producing the output

What I want is to have the bars on the y-axis extending in horizontal direction and not in vertical direction. That is, to somehow take the bar plot on the left and rotating it 90 degrees clockwise.
Is there a way to do this?

I've replaced the row sep=crcr parameter with row sep=\\ since the manual doesn't give a definition of crcr.
I've commented out the superfluous code.
To make it horizontal, I've named the columns A (Abscissa) and O (Ordinate). I've simply inverted the x-axis and y-axis with the parameters x=O and y=A.
\addplot[xbar interval,fill=mycolor1, fill opacity=0.6, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=newline,x=O,y=A]

Complete code
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
    %

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=3.208in,
    height=2.406in,
    at={(2.042in,1.531in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={x},
    ymin=-0.0732000000000001,
    ymax=1.2732,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={y},
    axis background/.style={fill=white}
    ]
    \addplot [color=mycolor1, only marks, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor1}%, forget plot
    ]
      table[row sep=\\]{%
    0.767861601282467   0.3458589136031\\
    0.756680548341953   0.95864147735458\\
    0.787814379362316   0.615634775664367\\
    0.482346943930302   0.140139439118997\\
    0.788420766278634   0.252324016431217\\
    0.609541593446003   0.833025781488994\\
    0.598497835040654   0.447882785562502\\
    0.962167060742761   0.297077799336121\\
    0.0672914051246174  0.829030827812664\\
    0.0685031200093895  0.257294078290989\\
    0.979842293331438   0.250600951574307\\
    0.679902746964661   0.934100057924172\\
    0.510673213422503   0.650716813847921\\
    0.650982431174077   0.324690703869729\\
    0.587879973826315   0.167319776765514\\
    0.25698833084105    0.271900912155622\\
    0.986921712124531   0.323353384105197\\
    0.624261860962849   0.330737351577275\\
    0.871562473469132   0.701588447496151\\
    0.148334408564265   0.503016243850673\\
    0.267655595945384   0.838096145967706\\
    0.43063392865761    0.877759753558797\\
    0.220588538068738   0.897891019472078\\
    0.729660418601116   0.899526138648854\\
    0.708895728868174   0.291546924111268\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=1.266in,
    height=2.406in,
    at={(0.19in,1.531in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    ymin=-0.012,
    ymax=1.212,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none
    ]
    \addplot[xbar interval,fill=mycolor1, fill opacity=0.6, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=newline,x=O,y=A] 
     {%
    A   O
    0   1.06666666666667
    0.3 0.8
    0.6 1.2
    0.9 0.266666666666667
    1.2 0.266666666666667
    };
%  Code commented as unnecessary below:
%    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
%      table[row sep=\\]{%
%    -0.0600000000000001 0\\
%    1.26    0\\
%    };
    \end{axis}
    
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=3.208in,
    height=0.827in,
    at={(2.042in,0.216in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    ymin=-0.0146666666666667,
    ymax=1.48133333333333,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none
    ]
    \addplot[ybar interval, fill=mycolor1, fill opacity=0.6, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=\\] {%
    x   y\\
    0   0.8\\
    0.3 0.666666666666667\\
    0.6 1.46666666666667\\
    0.9 0.4\\
    1.2 0.4\\
    };
    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
      table[row sep=\\]{%
    -0.0600000000000001 0\\
    1.26    0\\
    };
    \end{axis}

% Code commented as unnecessary below:   
%    \begin{axis}[%
%    width=5.833in,
%    height=4.375in,
%    at={(0in,0in)},
%    scale only axis,
%    xmin=0,
%    xmax=1,
%    ymin=0,
%    ymax=1,
%    axis line style={draw=none},
%    ticks=none,
%    axis x line*=bottom,
%    axis y line*=left
%    ]
%    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}



Not perfect yet, but you can rotate the axis, too:
...
    % ~~~ left histo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=1.266in,
    height=2.406in,
    at={(0.19in,1.531in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    ymin=-0.012,
    ymax=1.212,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    rotate=90   % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    ]
...


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/714865/rotate-axis-of-tikzpicture-to-show-bars-in-horizontal-direction

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
    %

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ Scatterplot in the middle ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=3.208in,
    height=2.406in,
    at={(2.042in,1.531in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={x},
    ymin=-0.0732000000000001,
    ymax=1.2732,
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={y},
    axis background/.style={fill=white}
    ]
    \addplot [color=mycolor1, only marks, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor1}, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0.767861601282467   0.3458589136031\\
    0.756680548341953   0.95864147735458\\
    0.787814379362316   0.615634775664367\\
    0.482346943930302   0.140139439118997\\
    0.788420766278634   0.252324016431217\\
    0.609541593446003   0.833025781488994\\
    0.598497835040654   0.447882785562502\\
    0.962167060742761   0.297077799336121\\
    0.0672914051246174  0.829030827812664\\
    0.0685031200093895  0.257294078290989\\
    0.979842293331438   0.250600951574307\\
    0.679902746964661   0.934100057924172\\
    0.510673213422503   0.650716813847921\\
    0.650982431174077   0.324690703869729\\
    0.587879973826315   0.167319776765514\\
    0.25698833084105    0.271900912155622\\
    0.986921712124531   0.323353384105197\\
    0.624261860962849   0.330737351577275\\
    0.871562473469132   0.701588447496151\\
    0.148334408564265   0.503016243850673\\
    0.267655595945384   0.838096145967706\\
    0.43063392865761    0.877759753558797\\
    0.220588538068738   0.897891019472078\\
    0.729660418601116   0.899526138648854\\
    0.708895728868174   0.291546924111268\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    
    % ~~~ left histo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=1.266in,
    height=2.406in,
    at={(0.19in,1.531in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    ymin=-0.012,
    ymax=1.212,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
    rotate=90   % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    ]
    \addplot[ybar interval, 
    fill=mycolor1, fill opacity=0.6, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
    x   y\\
    0   1.06666666666667\\
    0.3 0.8\\
    0.6 1.2\\
    0.9 0.266666666666667\\
    1.2 0.266666666666667\\
    };
%    % ~~~ just a line ~~~
%    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
%      table[row sep=crcr]{%
%    -0.0600000000000001 0\\
%    1.26    0\\
%    };
    \end{axis}
    
    % ~~~ lower histo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=3.208in,
    height=0.827in,
    at={(2.042in,0.216in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-0.0732000000000001,
    xmax=1.2732,
    ymin=-0.0146666666666667,
    ymax=1.48133333333333,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none
    ]
    \addplot[ybar interval, fill=mycolor1, fill opacity=0.6, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
    x   y\\
    0   0.8\\
    0.3 0.666666666666667\\
    0.6 1.46666666666667\\
    0.9 0.4\\
    1.2 0.4\\
    };
    \addplot [color=black, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    -0.0600000000000001 0\\
    1.26    0\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    
    % ~~~ not needed ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%    \begin{axis}[%
%    width=5.833in,
%    height=4.375in,
%    at={(0in,0in)},
%    scale only axis,
%    xmin=0,
%    xmax=1,
%    ymin=0,
%    ymax=1,
%    axis line style={draw=none},
%    ticks=none,
%    axis x line*=bottom,
%    axis y line*=left
%    ]
%    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}


